# creating a list from two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, list

I have two tables in my database:

```
table name:    Table1     Table2
columns        id1;name1  id2;name2;id1
```

I would like to output a nested list of items using PHP:

```
<ul>
    <li>item1 (from t1)</li>
    <li>item2 (from t1)</li>
    <li>item3 (from t1)
            <ul>
            <li>item1 (from t2 where id1 -> item3)</li>
            <li>item2 (from t2 where id1 -> item3)</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    <li>item4 (from t1)</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I would like to do this serverside but would also welcome any suggestions using CSS.
Many thanks for your time.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got it now:

The query is:

```
SELECT name1,name2 
FROM Table1 left join Table2 on Table1.id1=Table2.id1 
ORDER by Table1.id
```

id1 in Table2 is foreign key = Table1.id1

Then is this PHP code to generate html list:

```
echo "<ul>";

    $a ="";  // helpers
    $b = 0;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            if (isset($row['name2']) and $row['name1'] != $a and $b == 0) {

                echo "<li>".$row['name1']."<ul>";
                echo "<li>".$row['name2']."</li>";
                $a = $row['name1'];
                $b = 1;

            } 

            elseif (isset($row['name2']) and $row['name1'] == $a and $b == 1) {

                echo "<li>".$row['name2']."</li>";

            }

            elseif (isset($row['name2']) and $row['name1'] != $a and $b == 1) {

                echo "</ul>";
                echo "<li>".$row['name1']."<ul>";
                echo "<li>".$row['name2']."</li>";
                $a = $row['name1'];
                $b = 1;

            }

            elseif (!isset($row['name2']) and $row['name1'] !=$a and $b == 1) {

                echo "</ul>";
                echo "<li>".$row['name1']."</li>";
                $a = $row['name1'];
                $b = 0;

            }

            else {
                echo "<li>".$row['name1']."</li>";
                $a = $row['name1'];
                $b = 0;

            }
        }

    echo "</ul>";
```

Just to add that there can be no name2 without name 1 and name 1 can have no name2.

Answer (score 0):

I would reference this site for printing out the results of a SQL query via PHP:

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/display_table_data.htm

As for the SQL query, your suggested query doesn't match your desired output since the suggested HTML list has 3 items requested from table1, but your suggested table1 has only 2 items.

Maybe look like this?

```
SELECT     T1.id1, T1.name1, T2.id2, T2.name2
FROM         dbo.table1 as T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 as T2 ON T1.Id1 = T2.Id1
```

That would give you a "grid" output that can be read by PHP and formatted as a list, as you suggested.  It's really only 4 columns because one of the 5 is redundant.